# Showing JavaDoc/ScalaDoc for Maven/Sbt managed projects in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 Ultimate. For not Maven-managed or Sbt-managed Java/Scala projects, autopop documentation showed up fine. But for Maven/Sbt managed projects, JavaDoc/ScalaDoc does not show up. The dialog box will appear but there's nothing inside.

Comment: Did you check that your intellij settings are setup for automatic importing sources/docs for Maven? Did you construct your intellij project as import from Maven?

Comment: Sources are already downloaded in the Maven repository. I start a new Maven/Sbt project in IntellJ. Even JavaDocs written in source wouldn't show up if the project is managed by Maven/Sbt. But if not managed by Sbt/Maven, all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured source path for JDK/SDK correctly (Project structure -> SDKs)
and Maven is configured to download sources/docs automatically (Maven -> Importing).

You can also check Settings -> Editor -> Show quick doc on mouse move setting.

Comment: Even JavaDocs written in source wouldn't show up if the project is managed by Maven/Sbt.

Comment: You can also check Settings -> Editor -> Show quick doc on mouse move setting.